# How to graph from CSV into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, r, csv

I'm trying to create a html page that has an interactive graph that is constantly updating from a local CSV file on my computer. None of these processes will be online. The R code that I have written automatically updates the local CSV file.

I've tried several tools like dygraph, plotly and d3 to create it but I run into problems in each one. My question is: how do I create a line graph from a csv in the html code?

This is what the data looks like:

```
data.frame(
    sentiment = c(0.09589028, 0.014308793), 
    date = c(21/05/2019, 22/05/2019)
)

   sentiment        date
1 0.09589028 0.002080238
2 0.01430879 0.002179297
```

Answer (score 0):

I expanded the original dataset a bit to make it look nicer than a linechart with just two lines ;-). I recommend using the `highcharter` package for the visualisation and `lubridate` for the formatting.

```
library(highcharter)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
    sentiment = c(0.09589028, 0.014308793, 0.42344, 0.45552), 
    date = c("21/05/2019", "22/05/2019", "23/05/2019", "24/05/2019")
)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%y")

highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(data = df, type = "line", hcaes(date, sentiment)) %>%
    hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I used htmlwidgets::savewidget() to save it and it seems to be able to overwrite any files automatically. Is there a way to directly use html scripts to create this line graph from the csv? Or is that way more complicated?

Comment: great! If my answer was helpful please accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/).  I have had success in the past using D3 to import the CSV file using the Chart.js API.  There is a more in depth article [here](https://www.createwithdata.com/chartjs-and-csv/).